# Number of partitions with x parts

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

I might be wrong, but this is how I define "parts" when talking about partitions:

The partition 1+1+1 has 3 parts. The partition 1+2+2 has 3 parts. The numbers, whether they be distinct or not, do not matter: it is the number of digits that matter.

The partitions of 5 are as follows: 1+1+1+1+1 = 1+1+1+2 = 1+2+2 = 1+1+3 = 2+3 = 1+4 = 5

Of those 7 partitions, two of them consist of 3 parts (1+2+2 and 1+1+3). Two of them consist of 2 parts (2+3 and 1+4).

The number of parts is defined as the variable $x$, and the number being partitioned is defined as the variable $n$. I want an equation that gives the number of partitions with $x$ amount of parts, when $n$ is partitioned. The in-values are $x$ and $n$, and the out-value is the number of partitions with $x$ amount of parts.

Let's say that the no. of partitions consisting of $x$ parts is defined as the variable $y$.

**Here's what I know:**

There are three constants: If $x = 1, n, (n-1)$ then $y = 1$, **regardless** of the $n$-value.

To show this, look at the partitions of 5 again. Only one partition has an $x$-value of 1, and that is the partition 5. Only one partition has an $x$-value of $n$, and that is the partition of 1+1+1+1+1. Only one partition has an $x$-value of $n-1$, and that is the partition of 1+1+1+2.

I hope this was clearer. I have edited this question drastically, because I think I worded myself unclearly in the first edition.

**EDIT:** My question is this: Is there an equation for determining $y$, based off of $n$ and $x$?

Comment: In the "Partition" article in Wikipedia, your "component" is also called a "part", defined by "a summand in a partition". The section "Restricted part size or number of parts" provides a recursive relation and a generating function.

Comment: @player3236 thanks I will check it out

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking for the number $p_k(n)$ of partitions of a number $n$ into exactly $k$ parts. This is a standard type of [restricted partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_partitions) problem and can be solved as follows. Given such a partition, "rotate the [Ferrers diagram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FerrersDiagram.html)," which shows that $p_k(n)$ also counts the number of partitions of a number $n$ whose largest part has size exactly $k$. Removing this part produces a partition of $n-k$ whose largest part has size at most $k$, and using this we can show that for fixed $k$ this sequence has a very nice [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) given by

$$P_k(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} p_k(n) x^n = \frac{x^k}{\prod_{i=1}^k (1 - x^i)}$$

which in principle allows you to write down a closed form for $p_k(n)$ (again, for fixed $k$; it gets more complicated the larger $k$ is), although I won't do so. As a random example, setting $k = 5$ gives

$$\begin{align} \sum_{n \ge 0} p_5(n) x^n &= \frac{x^5}{(1 - x)(1 - x^2)(1 - x^3)(1 - x^4)(1 - x^5)} \\ &= x^5 + x^6 + 2x^7 + 3x^8 + 5x^9 + 7x^{10} + 10x^{11} + 13x^{12} + 18x^{13} + \dots \end{align}$$

which shows, for example, that the number of partitions $p_5(13)$ of $13$ into exactly $5$ parts is $18$. $p_5(n-5)$, which also counts the number $p_{\le 5}(n)$ of partitions of $n$ into at most $5$ parts, turns out to be [A001401](http://oeis.org/A001401) on the OEIS.

Among other things, this generating function can be used to deduce the asymptotic growth rate of $p_k(n)$ (for fixed $k$, as $n \to \infty$), which turns out to be

$$p_k(n) \sim \frac{n^{k-1}}{(k-1)! k!}.$$

**Edit:** Okay, mea culpa - I said I'd write down the closed form you get from the generating function but for large $k$ I am really not sure how to do it even in a messy way. The basic strategy is to compute the [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) of the generating function $P_k(x)$ above. This gets very messy in general; here's what you get for small values of $k$.

For $k = 1$ there is a unique partition of $n$ with $1$ part, namely $n = n$. This corresponds to the generating function

$$P_1(x) = \frac{x}{1 - x} = x + x^2 + x^3 + \dots $$

which gives $\boxed{ p_1(n) = 1 }$ if $n \ge 1$ and $0$ if $n = 0$. Pretty straightforward.

For $k = 2$ the partial fraction decomposition is

$$P_2(x) = \frac{x^2}{(1 - x)(1 - x^2)} = \frac{1}{2(1 - x)^2} - \frac{3}{4(1 - x)} + \frac{1}{4(1 + x)}$$

(this can be done by hand) which gives the already-surprisingly-complicated

$$\boxed{ p_2(n) = \frac{n}{2} + \frac{(-1)^n - 1}{4} }.$$

This can be simplified, and proven, with a little casework as follows. The partitions into two parts are $n = i + j$ where, if $i \ge j$, we have $1 \le j \le \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$. So we get $\boxed{ p_2(n) = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor }$ which is equivalent to the above after squinting a bit.

For $k = 3$ the partial fraction decomposition is (according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fraction+x%5E3+%2F+%28%281+-+x%29%281+-+x%5E2%29%281+-+x%5E3%29))

$$P_3(x) = \frac{-x^2 + 20x - 7}{72(1 - x)^3} - \frac{8}{1 + x} + \frac{x + 2}{9(1 + x + x^2)}$$

which gives, using that $\frac{x + 2}{1 + x + x^2} = \frac{2 - x - x^2}{1 - x^3}$ and $-x^2 + 20x - 7 = - (1 - x)^2 - 18(1 - x) + 12$, and after some simplification,

$$\boxed{ p_3(n) = \frac{6n^2 - 7}{72} - \frac{(-1)^n}{8} + \frac{\omega_3(n)}{9} }$$

where $\omega_3(n)$ is a periodic function with period $3$ that repeats $2, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, \dots $. Already it's not entirely obvious that this is an integer, and I can't claim not to have made any computational errors, but the result has to look something like this even if I messed something up. It only gets worse from here - $p_k(n)$ has period-$d$ components for every $1 \le d \le k$. You can check out the partial fraction decomposition for $k = 4$ for yourself [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions+of+x%5E4+%2F+%28%281+-+x%29%281+-+x%5E2%29%281+-+x%5E3%29%281+-+x%5E4%29%29).

So there's an important sense in which it's hopeless to expect a closed form for large $k$, although as above the leading-order asymptotic in $n$ for fixed $k$ is easy to calculate and the next few terms might not be so bad either. The good news is that for many purposes it doesn't matter; the generating function is powerful enough to answer many questions you might have about partitions with restricted parts.

Comment: No this was not what I meant. Searching for partitions of 13, I saw that a Wikipedia article stated it had 18 partitions consisting of distinct parts, so I assume that's what this answer is for. However, that's not what I was looking for. I want the number of partitions that contain a certain number of parts. 1+3+3 contains 3 parts, 1+4+3+3 contains 4 parts, 1+1+1+1+1 contains 5 parts, and so on. I want to know how many partitions with a certain number of parts a partitioned number has. To exemplify this; 5 has 2 partitions consisting of 3 parts, those being 1+1+3 and 1+2+2.

Comment: I've edited my question to be more clear now.

Comment: @A.Kvåle: that is exactly the question I’m answering here.

Comment: I have some questions regarding the variables: so the n-value is the number being partitioned, right? Is then the k-value the number of parts, or is that  the x-value?

Comment: @A.Kvåle: $k$ is the number of parts, which I guess is what you're calling the $x$-value.

Comment: But then what is the $x$-value in your answer?

Comment: @A.Kvåle: I don't understand your question. I just said it was $k$.

Comment: Yes, but that leaves the x-value still pending an explanation. The $n$-value is the number being partitioned, $k$ is the number of parts, but then what is $x$? In my post, I only mentioned two input variables, yet here is a third one. What does it signify?

Comment: @A.Kvåle: as I have already said twice, $k = x$.

Comment: When I say $x$-value, I'm talking about the one featured in the expression $P_k (n) x^n$ that's in front of the sigma expression. I'm not talking about the $x$-value as I defined it in my post, as that variable is translated into the $k$-value in your post. So, **my** question's $x$ = to **your** answer's $k$. However, I'm wondering about what **your** question's $x$ signifies, the one that's a part of the aforementioned expression.

Comment: @A.Kvåle: oh, I see. $x$ is a formal variable used to define the generating function, it doesn't have an independent meaning. It just turns out that the easiest way to describe $p_k(n)$ is in terms of a generating function. You can consult, for example, Wilf's *generatingfunctionology*: https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html

Comment: Does that mean that the value of $x$ will be different from case to case? I'm trying to create a general formula, where the number of partitions of a certain number of parts is very relevant. If the $x$-value is different in every case than that creates some issues. I'm reading the linked article by the way, seems quite interesting.

Comment: @A.Kvåle: $x$ does not have a value. It is a formal variable whose role is to have the property that the coefficient of $x^n$ in the generating function is $p_k(n)$. You can write down a general formula for fixed $k$ but it will get annoying fast. $k = 1, 2$ will look okay but even $k = 3$ will be a little annoying and $k = 4$ will be pretty annoying, I think. I can edit in what these formulas look like if you're very interested.

Comment: Well the thing is, I'd like a formula/equation where $k$ and $n$ can be anything, but the equation will still give an answer, which I called $y$ in my post.

Comment: @A.Kvåle: you can extract such a formula from the generating function but it will have $k$ terms. I think it is not possible to do better than this. Do you want me to write it down?

Comment: If you could do that, I'd greatly appreciate it:) Might grasp what is going on better then

Comment: You can use partial fractions to express the generating function in a form from which you can extract the kind of formula you want but, as Qiaochu says, it will be fairly unpleasant, and the larger the number of parts, the more unpleasant it will be.

Comment: The case $k=5$ is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A026811 where the formula $a(n) = {\rm round}( ((n^4+10(n^3+n^2)-75n -45n(-1)^n)) / 2880 )$ is given.

Comment: Didn't see your edit until now for some reason; thank you very much. I'll have to find another way to integrate these partitions parts into my formula, because a large point of the formula is that it is general, but all of this was still helpful. Also quite interesting to learn about the whole aspect of generating functions.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The function $f_3(n)$ can be written in a more compact way as $\lfloor \frac{n^2}{12}\rceil$, where $\lfloor \cdot \rceil$ denotes rounding to the closest integer. I wonder if there is a nice direct proof of that formula, without generating functions.